# c jack-audio-connection-kit: how to properly play a song if my sound card sample rate differs from the song's?

Tags: c, audio, jack

I'm using libsndfile to load the music file and i use jack to play it.

how do I resolve issues when the sample rate of the song is lower or higher then the sample rate of my sound card? is there something i can configure in jack or do i need to use libsamplerate to convert the sample rate ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jack does not resample.
there is a library called libsamplerate that converts from one sample rate to another. I can use it to convert a song to the sound card's sample rate.